# accessing angular HTML from custom controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-formly

OK, I have a custom template I am using where i have several accordions containing lists where the user can click on the option and it becomes active.  However I cannot access the parent scope in the controller to change remove the active class from the previously clicked item.

Basically what I want is when a user clicks on a list item, it becomes active and the other items become inactive.

Here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/d5kHjH?p=preview

Here is the pertinent code:

```
.run(function(formlyConfig) {
    formlyConfig.setType({
      name: 'label',
      template: `<div ng-init= "active = false">
      <a li class="list-group-item small" ng-click="addActive(); active = !active" ng-class="{'active': active === true}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>   {{to.label}}</li></a>
      </div>`,
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.addActive = function() {
                $(this).parent().children().removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("active");
                $scope.model.PROC = $scope.to.label;
                console.log($scope.model.PROC);
        };
      }
    });
  })
```

I want to be able to add the inactive class to the previously created items, which are being called from an ng-repeat from here in the HTML:

```
    <uib-accordion close-others="true">
            <ul class="list-group">
              <div uib-accordion-group="" class="panel-primary" ng-repeat="accordion in vm.accordions" active="accordion.active" is-open="isopen">
                <uib-accordion-heading ng-click="isopen=!isopen">

                  <span class="label label-info pull-left">{{accordion.label}}</span>
{{accordion.title}}
                  </uib-accordion-heading>
                <formly-form model="accordion.form.model" fields="accordion.form.fields" form="vm.form" options="accordion.form.options"></formly-form>
              </div>
            </ul>
          </uib-accordion>
```

The formly-form line is where the template item are being added in on by one

Comment: The Plunker is not related with this problem, is it? Please check the link.

Comment: I guess maybe the bigger question is why calling ```$('li').removeClass("active");``` inside the controller has no effect?

Comment: Hi Matt E,
The plunk link is not related to your question. If you want us to help, please try to update the link. There are several answer to your question but a better answer depends on the your context.

Comment: I got it to work ho I needed it to by doing the following:  ```template: `<div ng-init= "active = false">
      <label class="list-group-item small" onclick="$('label').removeClass('active'); $(this).addClass('active')" ng-click="addModel()" ng-class="{'active': active === true}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>   {{to.label}}</label>
      </div>```